Is it possible to find the opposite of any given "thing"
Premise 1: A "thing" is something that can be described with properties (this is just for clarification it includes everything there is)
Premise 2: There are no two "things" with the exact same properties (this makes sense since both would be the same otherwise)
Premise 3: One can find the opposite of every property there is. (This one is the part I'm a bit uncertain about. For example the opposite of cold would be hot but the opposite of red isn't that easy to establish. The question is if there are finite possible opposites for any given property. As long as that's the case it should be possible to establish opposites for any given "thing", even tho there would probably be A LOT of options for more complex "things")
If all the premises are true it would mean that it indeed is possible to find the opposite of any given "thing" as one could theoretically find all necessary properties of any given "thing" and find out the possible opposites of each property to get a list of possible opposites of said thing.
EDIT: I just thought about it again. This assumes that the opposite of a thing is the same as the opposites of it's properties which might not be the case but I'm not sure

Quite vague you use of "opposite": the opposite of white is not black; it is not-black.

Having said that, also if we can agree about Premise 3, from the fact that the opposite of mortal is not-mortal, it does not follows that there are immortal "things". There is no reason to assume that every conceivable property must be instantiated.

If the "length" property of a thing is "1 inch", what's the opposite property? "2 inches"? "1 mile"? "1 cm"? "0 inches"?

How hot is hot? The sun's surface? The interior? A supernova? The Big Bang? If there is only one hot thing, there can only be one cold thing. You've consigned existence to mediocrity!

Premise 1 is either trivial or vacuous. Without a characterization of allowed properties and a plausible argument that those are enough to distinguish things, it is hard to see how it says anything cogent. For any thing A, we can cook up a 'property' of "being A" and then, of course, A will be describable by this 'property'.  And if this is allowed then the whole argument is circular, Premise 3 simply asserts what is concluded in different words.

In addition to David Gudeman's answer which questions the validity of premise 3, I would also question the validity of premise 1.
Things in the real world (and in any reasonably interesting hypothetical world) aren't just tuples of property values. Properties are assigned labels, and as such they are not fully objective but very much subjective, and don't completely specify a thing but mostly serve to identify and distinguish different things. This means that the list of properties used to describe a thing is normally incomplete and depends on the context.

It isn't the case that every property has an opposite, and even if everything did have an opposite, that wouldn't guarantee that every object has a corresponding object with all properties opposite.
You gave one example of a property with no opposite in your question: redness does not have an opposite. Other examples include "sounding like a flute", and "tasting like lemon". It's hard to see how one could come up with an opposite for any property that can't be arranged on a linear scale.
Even if there is a theoretical opposite to a property, that doesn't mean that there is actually something that has that property. If we are talking about the natural numbers, then one property that all natural numbers have is "being even or odd". The opposite property would be "being neither even nor odd", and no natural number has that property.

Which property doesn't have an opposite?
Why doesn't it guarantee that there is a theoretical "thing" that has the opposite properties of a different given "thing"?

@M.B. I've updated my answer to answer this question.

Even many/most? linear scales don't have opposites. Examples from comments on the question include length and temperature.

A property of is a measurable quality of a thing. Measurable qualities can be categorical (2 to N categories) or continuous (having infinitely gradated possible values).
The term 'opposite' implies a property of a thing that counterbalances or negates the same property on uniquely different thing. Thus, two people facing each other across a table have 'opposite' positions; blue is 'opposite' yellow on a color wheel, and 'opposite' red on the spectrum of human vision; a mountain top is 'opposite' a valley floor. 'Opposite' entails both separation and direction; something 'opposite' must be both away from and counter-facing its opposition.
The problem here is that the term opposite is both linear and relative. Something can only be 'opposite' along a specific dimension, given a specific frame of reference. The moment we begin joining properties together we create a multidimensional framework — with each property on its on axis — and the concept of being 'opposed' becomes complex. I mean, the thing we call a 'square' has several basic properties:

four sides
equal side length
equal angles of intersection
closure

and while we could imagine opposites for each or these measurable properties individually, within given frameworks, it's hard to imagine a framework that would uniquely specify opposites for all of the properties. In some frameworks, the opposite of a square will be a circle; in other frameworks, the opposite of a square will be a line or a cross… past one or two dimension. there's no easy or obvious point we can select to balance opposition

There is a problem with the premise 3.
Take for the example of the property (not containing an elephant) that is true of some room or house or instant of time. there is an infinite number of properties that contradict this property like the property of containing an elephant and the properties of containing two elephants,...etc. Talking about a "finite" number of contradictory properties seems nonsense to me.

Yes, this is a kind of reductio ad absurdum refutation.

Premisse 1 sounds more like a definition, not like a statement. But it doesn't make clear whether or not mathematical things, like numbers, are "things" too -- don't they have properties?
Premisse 2 sounds like an axiom. If we restrict ourselves to physical objects, are you then saying that there is only one electron in the universe? Premisse 2 would only be true, I think, if "being in location x at time y" would also be seen as a property of the object - which seems a rather unusual use of the word "property".
In premisse 3 it's not really clear to me what you mean by "opposite". Is the opposite of "(it is) red": "(it is) not red"? And an "opposite of thing x" would be a thing y that has none of the properties that x has? If so, you would usually be able to find an opposite of any thing x - but the problem would be, you'd have lots of totally different kinds of opposites.
(Also, there is a hidden assumption here, that you can indeed enumerate all the properties of a thing x. It's not clear to me that we can.)
An unrestricted, totally generally use of "property" would also lead to Russell's paradox. A barber is someone who has the property that he shaves those men who don't shave themselve. Does the barber shave himself?
